# Is there a way to get list of apps in firebase via API

Tags: firebase

I have created a project in firebase which has 10 apps in it. Is there a way to get the list of apps in that project via API? So far I found this

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
  "https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/apps"
```

I have create a new private key in service accounts to the the token but still getting 404. Is there any API provided by google?